# R data table group by with no j argument

Tags: r, data.table

How do you group a data table by some columns without providing a j argument?  For example, suppose you have the table

```
dt<-data.table(x=c("a","b","b","b"),y=c(1,1,1,2),z=c(1,2,3,4))
dt
   x y z
1: a 1 1
2: b 1 2
3: b 1 3
4: b 2 4
```

If you want to sum z for unique combinations of x and y, you can do

```
dt[,list(z=sum(z)),by=list(x,y)]
   x y z
1: a 1 1
2: b 1 5
3: b 2 4
```

but what if you just want the unique combinations of x and y?  I often find myself wanting to do something like

```
dt[,list(),by=list(x,y)]
```

or

```
dt[,,by=list(x,y)]
```

but neither works.  Is

```
unique(dt[,list(x,y)])
```

the only/fastest/easiest way to get what I want?

Comment: along your line of thought - `(dt[, 1, by = list(x, y)][, V1 := NULL])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`unique(dt[, list(x,y)])` makes a copy due to the *subset*. The idiomatic way to do this would be:

```
unique(dt, by=c("x", "y"))
```

If you don't want the `z` col, then you can simply remove it using `:=` by chaining as follows:

```
ans <- unique(dt, by=c("x", "y"))[, z := NULL]
```

Also have a look at `?unique` for more info.